# ADD NEW TODO LIST ITem

Tags: javascript

The goal is to create a new todo list when NEW TODO button is clicked the below is my starter script can anybody help me out?

```
const classNames = {
  TODO_ITEM: 'todo-container',
  TODO_CHECKBOX: 'todo-checkbox',
  TODO_TEXT: 'todo-text',
  TODO_DELETE: 'todo-delete',
}

const list = document.getElementById('todo-list')
const itemCountSpan = document.getElementById('item-count')
const uncheckedCountSpan = document.getElementById('unchecked-count')
<div class="container center">
  <h1 class="center title">My TODO App</h1>
  <div class="flow-right controls">
    <span>Item count: <span id="item-count">0</span></span>
    <span>Unchecked count: <span id="unchecked-count">0</span></span>

  </div>
  <button class="button center" onClick="newTodo()">New TODO</button>
  <ul id="todo-list" class="todo-list"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? I can see that this question is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61917964/add-new-todo-list). If your question is closed it's usually for good reason. Have you read [how to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Because this question looks like a [homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create that function `newTodo()`
2. Inside `newTodo`, get that `<ul>` element by its id (`todo-list`) and [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) `<li>` inside of it.

*And I'm not sure why you're storing that class names in an array*